# Mock object with turtle mock for boost::test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, turtle-mock

I'm trying to create a unittest with mocked objects using turtle and boost. But the example doesn't work and I can't find the error. I expect no errors but the result is:

```
$ ./unittest 
Running 1 test case...
Start
Display: 0
End
Calculator.spec.cpp(16): error in "zero_plus_zero_is_zero": untriggered expectation: v.MockView::display
. once().with( 0 )
```

Calculator.h:

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include "View.h"

class Calculator {
public:
    Calculator(View& v);

    void add( int a, int b ); // the result will be sent to the view 'v'
private:
    View& view;
};

#endif //CALCULATOR_H
```

Calculator.cpp:

```
#include "Calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator(View& v)
: view(v) {}

void Calculator::add(int a, int b) {
    view.display(a + b);
}
```

View.h:

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H

class View {
public:
    View() = default;

    void display(int a);
};

#endif //VIEW_H
```

View.cpp:

```
#include "View.h"
#include <iostream>

void View::display(int a) {
    std::cout << "Display: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

Calculator.spec.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE calculator
#include "Calculator.h"
#include "View.h"
#include <turtle/mock.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

MOCK_BASE_CLASS(MockView, View) {
    MOCK_METHOD(display, 1)
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( zero_plus_zero_is_zero ) {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    MockView v;
    Calculator calculator(v);
    MOCK_EXPECT(v.display).once().with(0);
    calculator.add(0, 0);
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

Makefile:

```
    test: Calculator.spec.cpp Calculator.cpp Calculator.h View.cpp View.h
        g++ Calculator.spec.cpp Calculator.cpp View.cpp -o unittest --std=c++11 -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

The unittest yields no errors when I change the test to

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( zero_plus_zero_is_zero ) {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    MockView v;
    Calculator calculator(v);
    MOCK_EXPECT(v.display).once().with(0);
    //calculator.add(0, 0);
    v.display(0);
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

What do I miss? Where is the problem with my test?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I forgot `virtual`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mock object is a subclass of `View` and it defines `display`. But because `display` is not declared `virtual` in `View`, the base class version is being called from the unit test instead of the mock version. You can observe this because `Display: 0` is present in the output of the unit test. Define `View::display` as `virtual` and it will work.